# Are all linear functions monotonic?

Tags: analysis, monotone-functions

I have never come across a statement linking linearity and monotony - but it seems that for each linear function (positive, negative or even constant slope), the function is monotonic:

I.e. for y $\geq$ x it follows that f(y) $\geq$ f(x).

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it's monotonic, but not necessarily increasing.  You could have $y\ge x\implies f(y)\le f(x)$

Comment: Exactly, so positive slope = increasing; negative slope = decreasing, in both cases strictly monotonic as well -- constant slope = monotonic, but not strictly. Is this correct?

Comment: Note that your question only makes sense for 1-dimensional functions, if you want to talk about linear functions in general, say $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ or any vector spaces then you need to define what you mean by $x\leq y$

Comment: @TestGuest yes this is the point.

Comment: @TestGuest Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily monotonic increasing, consider $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with $f(x)=-x$

clearly $f$ is linear but $1\geq 0$ and $f(1)=-1<0=f(0)$.

In general if $f$ is linear then so is $-f$ and it is impossible that both are monotonic increasing.

It is true however that every linear function is monotonic because every linear function from $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ takes the form $f(x)=ax$ where $a=f(1)$.

Comment: Thanks! How is a = f(1) a proof of monotonicity, however?

Comment: @TestGuest I just meant that $f(x)=ax$ is necessarily monotone. If $a>0$ it is increasing, if $a=0$ well it's constant and if $a<0$ then decreasing. The fact that $a=f(1)$ is unnecessary.